# Mask all elements of a window/canvas with C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, window, mask

How can I create a mask to cover ALL the elements of a Windows/Canvas (with subcanvas/elements inside)?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I want to add more controls/elements/whatever **after** I create the mask. Is that ok? How?

Comment: I'm always surprised that something so simple doesn't get any answers. Maybe MS is light years behind Adobe on this? Or there's something I don't understand about WPF/C#?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have to "mask" controls. Why don't you use the visibility property ?

For example, if you have a stackPanel and want to mask it and its content, just put

```
<StackPanel Visibility="Hidden">
...
</StackPanel>
```

By this way, you can control the visibility of each widget. If you want to "add" or make others visible, just set the Property to "Visible".

Comment: What if I want to hide only a half of it? (E.g.: for a sliding animation)

Comment: Maybe you should use other widget such as Expander, or tabs. An ugly solution would be to use a rectangle to mask your widgets, but I am convinced, even without knowing your program, that there is a smarter way to do this.

Firstly, it is a bit strange to mask UI elements... If you add widget, they must be visible, otherwise don't use them!
Secondly, to perform sliding animation, you can use common element like stack, grid or canvas and apply a animation to them between 2 states (visible -> hidden)